# Add code to CreateView when using POST method in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm using django's auth module to handle the user login, logout and registration in my website.

The problem is that when I register a new user, I new to redirect to another url, and then, since the model is created but doesn't automatically log in, I need to navigate to /login/ and log in manually.

I would like my site to do this automatically. By that I mean that:

- You click on the register button in home.html. You fill in the form and submit it.
- The website AUTOMATICALLY creates the new user model, logs you in and redirects you to home.html with the user logged in.

Urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from browse.views import UserCreate

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'',include('browse.urls')),
    url(r'^$', 'browse.views.home_page', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'browse/login.html'}),
    url(r'^register/$', UserCreate.as_view(
            template_name='browse/register.html',
            form_class=UserCreationForm,
            success_url='/register/'
    )),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'browse.views.logout_view', name='logout'),
    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and views.py looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from browse.models import Pattern
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import logout, login



class PatternCreate(CreateView):
    model = Pattern
    fields = ['name','description','license', 'xcheme', 'pictures', 'video']

class UserCreate(CreateView):
    model = User


    def post(self, request):
            return login(request, User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username']))

def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'browse/home.html')

def pattern_detail(request, pk):
    pattern = Pattern.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'browse/pattern_detail.html', {'pattern': pattern})

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

As you can see, when you GET /register/ the register form is rendered. When I POST to /register/, I want to execute the view as normally AND then add:

```
def post(self, request):
        return login(request, User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username']))
```

But It looks like I'm overriding the default view instead of adding to it, because the model doesn't get saved, since I get this error:

Exception Value:
User matching query does not exist.

How can I fix it?

Thank you so much beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it was a really dumb question. Luckily, I could figure it out:

```
def post(self, request):
    super(UserCreate, self).post(request)
    login_username = request.POST['username']
    login_password = request.POST['password1']
    created_user = authenticate(username=login_username, password=login_password)

    login(request, created_user)
    return redirect('/')
```

All I had to do is call super() and the parent function is executed. Then, my code executes.